# Append data from one sheet to another with date stamp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script which must copy the data from One spreadsheet to another along with date stamp.

I am unable to achieve this, can you help me with this as I am a newbie to scripting.

```
  function triggerOnTime() {
  var SpreadSheetKeyA = "MY key";
  var SpreadSheetKeyB = "MY key";
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet1.getRange(5,11,10,5).getValues();
  var time = new Date ();
  var array = [];
  for (var y = 1; y < data.length; y++) {

    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++){
      array.push(data[y][x]);
    }
      sheet2.appendRow([time,array]);
      array = []; //reset the array contents
      }
}
```

Spreadsheet-1: Data present in Spreadsheet-1,

```
Name     apple  android   windows    linux
Germany    3      4         6          7
America    4      1         6          2
Sweden     1      6         1          6
Paris      5      0         2          4
```

Spreadsheet-2: Data present in Spreadsheet-2,

```
Date   Name    apple  android   windows    linux
```

The data present in the spreadsheet-1 is  changed everyday. I would like to backup the data to spreadsheet-2 whenever new data is present in spreadsheet-1. It is like creating a log of data everyday with a date stamp.

Comment: Explain in detail whats not working.

Comment: now I have tried to explained, please go through it.

Comment: No. Problem is clear. Explain exaclty what doesnt work with the code shown.

Comment: "sheet2.appendRow([array]); " this works but when i add 'time' it doesn't. "sheet2.appendRow([time,array]);

Comment: Can you please explain where exactly to add the array.push(time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function triggerOnTime() {
  var SpreadSheetKeyA = "MY key";
  var SpreadSheetKeyB = "MY key";
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getSheetByName("Source Name");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getSheetByName("Target Name");
  var data = sheet1.getRange(5,11,10,5).getValues();
  var time = new Date ();
  for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    data[r].unshift(time);
    sheet2.appendRow(data[r]);
    }
}
```

data[r].unshift(time); adds the time to the beginning of the row array before appending to sheet2.

If there will be a significant number of additions to sheet2 in each run of the script appendRow() should not be used inside a loop and the array should be modified and then added to sheet2 in one operation as in the following

```
function triggerOnTime() {
  var SpreadSheetKeyA = "MY key";
  var SpreadSheetKeyB = "MY key";
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getSheetByName("Source Name");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getSheetByName("Target Name");
  var data = sheet1.getRange(5,11,10,5).getValues();
  var time = new Date ();
  for (var r = 1; r < data.length; r++) {
    data[r].unshift(time);
    }
  sheet2.insertRowsAfter(sheet2.getLastRow(), data.length);
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

You should use getSheetByName() instead of getActiveSheet(). Even if it works now adding a sheet later could mess things up when using triggers.

Comment: your script works perfect for me, but a minor enhancement is I have added `var time = new Date ().toJSON().slice(0,10); `

Comment: I would also like to delete the blank rows which are being updated in the sheet2 becoz of the range given in `var data = sheet1.getRange(5,11,10,5).getValues();`

Comment: that is a separate question. You should mark this one answered and post the new question with your new code.

Comment: Hi, I have posted a new question as you have suggested. Could you please help me. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626337/delete-blank-rows-in-spreadsheet-using-google-script]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the time inside the array and not as another parameter to appendrow. I.e. array.push(time) before you call appendRow. Or push it at the beginning of the array if you want it to be the first column.
also look at the other answer which shows how to optimize vy doing a single api call but you would need to modify the array to have the timestamp.

Comment: thanks you very much for your script, but The script given by ScampMichael is working perfect for me.  
I would also like to delete the blank rows which are being updated in the sheet2 becoz of the range given in `var data = sheet1.getRange(5,11,10,5).getValues();`