# Delete blank rows in spreadsheet using Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Spreadsheet-1: Data present in Spreadsheet-1,

```
Name     apple  android   windows    linux
Germany    3      4         6          7
America    4      1         6          2
Sweden     1      6         1          6
Paris      5      0         2          4
```

Spreadsheet-2: Data present in Spreadsheet-2,

```
Date   Name    apple  android   windows    linux
```

I am able to copy the data from spreadsheet1 to spreadsheet2 by using the below google script.

```
function Daily() {
  var SpreadSheetKeyA = "mykey1";
  var SpreadSheetKeyB = "mykey2";
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getSheetByName("Showstopper");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getSheetByName("Daily");
  var data = sheet1.getRange(5,11,40,6).getValues();
  var time = new Date ().toJSON().slice(0,10);;
  for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    data[r].unshift(time);
    sheet2.appendRow(data[r]);
    }
}
```

The data present in spreadsheet1 is dynamic i.e, the number of rows can vary. Now whenever I run the script again so as to update the spreadsheet2 data is being appended after blank rows. I would like enhance the above script so that it should avoid blank rows or only copy rows with data.

Can anyone help me with this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if all blanks are at the bottom of the source and there is nothing else below the data.

```
function triggerOnTime() {
  var SpreadSheetKeyA = "MY key";
  var SpreadSheetKeyB = "MY key";
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getSheetByName("Source Name");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getSheetByName("Target Name");
  var startRow = 5;
  var data = sheet1.getRange(startRow,11,sheet1.getLastRow() - startRow + 1,5).getValues();
  var time = new Date ().toJSON().slice(0,10);;
  for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    data[r].unshift(time);
    }
  if(data.length > 0 ) {
    sheet2.insertRowsAfter(sheet2.getLastRow(), data.length);
    sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason the above conditions cannot be met and you need to hardcode the number of rows to 40 you might try the following:

```
function triggerOnTime() {
      var SpreadSheetKeyA = "MY key";
      var SpreadSheetKeyB = "MY key";
      var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getSheetByName("Source Name");
      var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getSheetByName("Target Name");
      var startRow = 5;
      var data = sheet1.getRange(5,11,40,6).getValues();
      var time = new Date ().toJSON().slice(0,10);;
      for(var i = data.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if(data[i].join("").length == 0) data.splice(i, 1);
      }
      for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
        data[r].unshift(time);
        }
  if(data.length > 0 ) {
    sheet2.insertRowsAfter(sheet2.getLastRow(), data.length);
    sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }
    }
```

Comment: After using the above script, the data is being copied to the sheet2 but the date column  is getting folded with datestamp upto row 235 even though the data is only present until row 11.

Comment: which version are you using the top one or the bottom one?

Comment: you must have data entered in cells below the data you're trying to extract. try using the bottom version of the code and see if that works for you.

Comment: Could you please Help me with another question too,  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673020/delete-duplicate-rows-in-spreadsheet-using-google-script]