# How to, after deleting rows containing specific text, delete any adjacent row unless its blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script for cleaning up spread sheets, These sheets are generated automatically and they contain a lot of irrelevant information. I need to scan for a heading, delete that row and then delete each additional row until coming to a row thats completely blank, just before the next heading group:

I can use the code below to scan for target text and delete the row. 
I can log each row I deleted: Logger.log("deleted rows: " + toDelete );
But I'm having trouble writing the rest

```
function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var toDelete = [];
  var deleteExtra = [];

var re = new RegExp('(Member Service Associate|Contract Work)','gi'); 
  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) { 
  for(var column = 0;column<values[row].length;column++){ 
  if (re.exec(values[row][column])){
  toDelete.push(row); } } }


  for(var deleteRow = toDelete.length-1; deleteRow >= 0;deleteRow--){
    sheet.deleteRow(toDelete[deleteRow]+1);
}    
Logger.log("deleted rows: " + toDelete );
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

Logger output:

> [19-01-02 10:16:13:732 PST] deleted rows: 33,45,51,54,86,89,101,103,125,127,145,148,171,175,200,208,219,222,262,269,275,280,310,313,324,332,347,352,363,366,372,374,385,388

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/29626337/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6882104/1595451

Comment: Okay maybe there are some similar parts here but its a little unclear how to proceed

Comment: Can you share a copy of  your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

## Delete Unwanted and Adjacent Rows

Without having the benefit of being able to see your spreadsheets and you say that you want to keep deleting rows until you run into a blank row.

```
function deleteUnwantedAndAdjacentRows() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var d=0;//deleted count
  var kd=false;//keep deleting
  var re = new RegExp('(Member Service Associate|Contract Work)','gi'); 
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) { 
    if(vA[i].join("") && kd){//if something in this row and keep deleting is still true
      sh.deleteRow(i-d+1);//then delete
      d++;//increment delete count
      countinue;//go on to nextrow
    }else{//if row is blank
      kd=false;//quit deleting
    }
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){ 
      if(re.exec(vA[i][j])){
        sh.deleteRow(i-d+1);
        d++;
        kd=true;
      } 
    } 
  }    
}
```

Be sure to test this on something you can afford to mess up.